Building Accessibility Service for responding to USSD
I am trying to make accessibility services class for the following tasks in my app:

Sending request (eg. *121#)
Read response
Find a string inside the response
There will be a number before the string. Extract it
respond with the extracted number

This is my code so far
public class AccServices extends AccessibilityService {

    private static final String TAG = "AccServices";
    private static String ussdCode;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null && "com.example.testingaccessibility.ACTION_SEND_USSD".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            ussdCode = intent.getStringExtra("ussd_code");
            Log.d(TAG, "Received USSD Code: " + ussdCode);

            // Start USSD dialer
            if (ussdCode != null) {
                String ussdDialCode = ussdCode.replace("#", Uri.encode("#"));
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdDialCode));
                callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent");
        if (event.getClassName() != null && event.getClassName().equals("android.app.AlertDialog")) {
            List<CharSequence> eventText = event.getText();
            if (eventText != null && eventText.size() > 0) {
                StringBuilder ussdMessage = new StringBuilder();
                for (CharSequence text : eventText) {
                    ussdMessage.append(text);
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "USSD Message: " + ussdMessage.toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.testingaccessibility.ACTION_USSD_RECEIVED");
                intent.putExtra("ussd_message", ussdMessage.toString());
                sendBroadcast(intent);

                // Find the number before "GP STAR"
                String response = ussdMessage.toString();
                String numberBeforeGpStar = extractNumberBeforeGpStar(response);
                if (numberBeforeGpStar != null) {
                    respondToUssd(numberBeforeGpStar);
                }
                performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
            }
        }
    }

    private String extractNumberBeforeGpStar(String response) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+GP STAR");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String numberBeforeGpStar = matcher.group(1);
            // Show a Toast message with the number before "GP STAR"
            Toast.makeText(this, "Number before GP STAR: " + numberBeforeGpStar, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return numberBeforeGpStar;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void respondToUssd(String response) {
        AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode = getRootInActiveWindow();
        if (rootNode != null) {
            List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> inputNodes = rootNode.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.android.phone:id/inputField"); // Replace with actual input field ID
            if (inputNodes != null && !inputNodes.isEmpty()) {
                AccessibilityNodeInfo inputNode = inputNodes.get(0);
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, response);
                inputNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, args);

                // Find and click the send button
                List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> sendNodes = rootNode.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.android.phone:id/sendButton"); // Replace with actual send button ID
                if (sendNodes != null && !sendNodes.isEmpty()) {
                    AccessibilityNodeInfo sendNode = sendNodes.get(0);
                    sendNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                }
            }
            rootNode.recycle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Accessibility service interrupted");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        Log.d(TAG, "Accessibility service connected");
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED | AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED;
        info.packageNames = new String[]{"com.android.phone"};
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
        info.notificationTimeout = 0;
        setServiceInfo(info);
    }
}

So far, the code is working up to step 4, but I cannot respond because after the USSD request is sent (step 1), the USSD menu/response dialog box appears on the screen. I need to suppress it and keep it in the background so that I can send a response to it. This is the first issue.
The second issue is that I need to find the actual input field ID and the actual send button ID of the USSD dialogue box in order to interact with it. However, I don't know how to do this. I am desperate for a solution, so any help would be highly appreciated.
